# Transformation of values on $x$ and $y$ axis for a LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, logarithmic-scale

I have been puzzled by the following issue:

When I am using `LogLogPlot`, while the graph of the function is transformed into the corresponding logarithmic expression, the values on the `x` and `y` axes remain the same. A good example is the following, taken from the documentation:

```
LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 0.1, 10}]
```

[image]

When at `x=10` the value of `x^2` at $y$ axis should be, as correctly shown `100` but at a `LogLogPlot`, with `Log[10,x]` it should be: $\text{Log} (10^2)=2 \text{Log} 10=2$. Also, at `x=10` the $x$ axis should be equivalently $\text{Log 10} =1$. But none of this is happening.

How is it possible to tell *Mathematica* to show the logarithmic values of the function and not the original ones?

Comment: do a regular plot of the log of the function.

Comment: @george2079 Thank you for your comment. That solves the one part, I have thought of that. What about the $log$ value of the $x$ axes?

Comment: It seems to you are confusing a `LogLogPlot` of `x^2` with a `Plot` of `LogLog[10, x^2]`. They ar different beasts,

Comment: @m_goldberg I am saying that to a `LogLogPlot` of a function produces the graph of the function with axes `Log[f[x]]` and `Log[x]`. This is written in the documentation. My question has to do with the values on the axes. They do not correspond to logarithmic scale. Do they? What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Because as I said before, you are not plotting `Log[x^2}` -- you are plotting `x^2`, with the plot ***scaled*** by the  `Log` function.

Comment: @m_goldberg I thought that what the documentation means is that `LogLogPlot` plots the `Log[10,x^2]` versus `Log[10,x]`( or whatever base)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of ways:

Log-parametric plot:

```
ParametricPlot[Log10@{x, x^2}, {x, 0.1, 10}, AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Redefining the ticks (note that `LogLogPlot` transforms the coordinates by the natural logarithm, so the ticks have to be scaled by `Log[10]` to get common logarithm coordinate markings):

```
Show[LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 0.1, 10}], 
 Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{#*Log[10] &, #/Log[10] &}], 
   Charting`ScaledTicks[{#*Log[10] &, #/Log[10] &}]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05] (*OR*) (*AxesOrigin -> {Log[0.1],Log[0.01]}*)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Instead of `PlotRangePadding` (no vertical axis in V11.1.1 if omitted), one can also control the axes with [`AxesOrigin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesOrigin.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the second option works for me. I noticed that if I use `Frame->True`, I lose the value transformation. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Also, for some reason, in the function which I calculate (different from my example in the question), it seems have some values "cut-off" when I use your adjustment, even though the axis still looks as it should. It looks like I should play around with `AxesOrigin`

Comment: @Mitscaype With `Frame`, you use `FrameTicks` instead of `Ticks`: ``FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{#*Log[10] &, #/Log[10] &}], Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{#*Log[10] &, #/Log[10] &}]}, {Charting`ScaledTicks[{#*Log[10] &, #/Log[10] &}], Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{#*Log[10] &, #/Log[10] &}]}}``  --  Not sure what to say about your second comment. *M* does sometimes reduce the `PlotRange` when set to `Automatic`, but you may be talking about some other sort of cut-off than I'm imagining.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I will try to figure out the reason of the cut-off, if not I will come back :)